# Python listing directory without errors

Tags: python, list, operating-system, dir

I recently started making a program for a friend and when I try to make a directory lister with user input I cant figure out how to handle the error.
Directory Example

- Users
- Prefrences
- Memos

How do I make it so that is shows an error like 'Invalid Directory' if the user enters 'home'?

Here is my small ammount of code:

```
ch1 = input('Path To List: ')
path = ch1
dirList = os.listdir(path)
for fname in dirList:
    print('-', fname)
cmd()
```

Is there any code that I can include to fix that error?

Thanks!

Comment: `os.listdir` will raise an `OSError` exception if path is invalid... what more do you need? catch the exception and print an error message.

Comment: Have you even tested what you have so far? If the path/directory does not exist an exception is raised and the program will exit. Just add a try/except block to catch the error as @isedev said

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, a try/except block is enough to do what you want:

```
import os
import sys
# Get input as a string
input = raw_input('Path To List: ')
# Get absolute path in case user gives a relative path
path = os.path.abspath(input)
try:
    dirList = os.listdir(path)
except OSError:
    print("Invalid directory")
    sys.exit()
for fname in dirList:
    print(fname)
```